# Casting std::shared_ptr<Derived<T>> to std::shared_ptr<Base>

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2019

I have a base class and a templated derived class as below

```
class ComponentArray_Base
{
 public:
     virtual ~ComponentArray_Base() = default;              
     virtual void EntityDestroyed(Entity entity) = 0;       
};


template <typename cType>
class ComponentArray : public ComponentArray_Base
{
 //Derived class implementation...
}
```

and later in the code, outside of the two classes I attempt to add the derived class to an unordered map with

```
mComponentArrays.insert({ TypeName, std::make_shared<ComponentArray<cType>> });
```

which gives me the error

```
C:\Users\davis\source\repos\ECS\ECS\Component.h(91,1): error C2664: 'void std::_Hash<std::_Umap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,std::_Uhash_compare<_Kty,_Hasher,_Keyeq>,_Alloc,false>>::insert(std::initializer_list<std::pair<const char *const ,std::shared_ptr<ComponentArray_Base>>>)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'initializer list' to 'std::initializer_list<_Ty>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=const char *,
1>            _Ty=std::shared_ptr<ComponentArray_Base>,
1>            _Hasher=std::hash<const char *>,
1>            _Keyeq=std::equal_to<const char *>,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const char *const ,std::shared_ptr<ComponentArray_Base>>>
1>        ]
1>        and
1>        [
1>            _Ty=std::pair<const char *const ,std::shared_ptr<ComponentArray_Base>>
1>        ]
```

I do not seem to be having this problem when using a raw pointer and cannot figure out what the problem is as the hash function should be defined for const char*

Using std::static_ptr_cast as below also gives an error,

```
mComponentArrays.insert({ TypeName, std::static_pointer_cast<ComponentArray_Base>(std::make_shared<ComponentArray<cType>>) });
```

gives me

```
 'std::static_pointer_cast': none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\memory(2095,29): message : could be 'std::shared_ptr<ComponentArray_Base> std::static_pointer_cast<ComponentArray_Base,ComponentArray<cType>>(std::shared_ptr<ComponentArray<cType>> &&) noexcept'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            cType=Renderable
1>        ]
```

Comment: [std::static_pointer_cast](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/static_pointer_cast/)

Comment: If you say even explicit `static_pointer_cast` fails you should double-check the inheritance, maybe you forgot `public` in `class ComponentArray : public ComponentArray_Base`. But it is usually should not be needed to explicitly cast from derived to base.

Comment: You are not inserting `shared_ptr`, you are trying to insert a pointer to function. You forgot to actually call `make_shared`

Answer (score 0):

I successfully compile below example. Did I miss sth?

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class ComponentArray_Base
{
 public:
     virtual ~ComponentArray_Base() = default;              
     virtual void EntityDestroyed(int entity) = 0;       
};


template <typename cType>
class ComponentArray : public ComponentArray_Base
{
    void EntityDestroyed(int entity) override
    {
        return;
    }
 //Derived class implementation...
};

std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<ComponentArray_Base>> mComponentArrays;

int main()
{
    mComponentArrays.insert({ "Sth", std::make_shared<ComponentArray<int>>() });

    return 0;
}
```